# Validation rule to prevent users from closing cases before 9am

Tags: formula, validation-rule, validation

I want a validation rule that should prevent users from changing the status of a case to close before 9am. I wrote the following rule but it is giving me missing ')' syntax error:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Closed"),
    TIMENOW() < TIMEVALUE(08:00:00) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time you pass to `TIMEVALUE()` needs to be enclosed in quotes (single or double).

`TIMEVALUE("09:00:00")`

Comment: thank you Derek this worked for me.